# Cannot get User's profile image to display in another object

Tags: user, images

I have a custom object named `Student__c`, which has a lookup Field `User__c` to User. I want to create a formula field `Avatar__c` in `Student__c` to get the User's profile image to display in this object.
I saw there is a standard field named `MediumPhotoUrl` in the `User` object. But I cannot access this field in the `Avatar__c` formula field. Is there any way to access the user profile image?

Here is my `Student__c` object:
[image]

The `User` object has `Url for medium profile photo` standard field. My User object doesn't have FullPhotoUrl (and I don't know why)
[image]

I cannot also add `MediumPhotoUrl` to `Avatar__c` formula field. `Error: Field MediumPhotoUrl does not exist. Check spelling.`
[image]

Hope someone can help me with this problem. If we couldn't get the picture from User, do we have another way to upload picture to `Student__c` object? Thank you!

Answer (score 1):

Unfortunately, you cannot access 'MediumPhotoUrl' in formula fields.  You would need to use apex,flow etc., to access MediumPhotoUrl field.

Kindly review limitation [here](https://ideas.salesforce.com/s/idea/a0B8W00000GdXZIUA3/user-chatter-photos-in-declarative-formulas-usersmallphotourl).

Also check how to [Use Images in 'Formula' Fields](https://help.salesforce.com/s/articleView?id=000385501&type=1) along with [Graphics Pack](https://appexchange.salesforce.com/listingDetail?listingId=a0N30000004cfIcEAI&tab=r) appexchange tool.

Comment: Hi @Vinay, thanks for your answer. I checked your solution but the Library seems to be available for Salesforce Classic, not Lightning Experience. I couldn't find Libraries in my org. Do you have any solution for Lightning Experience?

Comment: I am using Salesforce Developer Edition btw

Comment: Type “Files” on app launcher--> click libraries on the left-hand panel --> click on 'New Library'.  You can also check Appexchange tool update on answer